# SSIS flat file to ftp server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ftp, connection-string

I have an SSIS package (using 2008 R2) that I would like sent to my FTP server. In the Flat File Connection Manager under the connection string I've put the address \stp-ftp\RMB as the location that I would like the file to be placed but each  time I close the connection manager it reverts back to my original location. Is there a way correct this? The share drive that I'm attempting to send the file to hasn't been mapped on the sql server where I'm working is that what needs to happen?

Thanks -

Comment: It could be the share drive mapping, or it could be something else.   Can you try using a UNC path instead of a share drive?

Comment: Is there any chance that the destination value is being modified by an expression?

Comment: That was the UNC path that I was using \\stp-ftp\RMB (\\server\share\file name when created) I have it working just not sure why it's working now. I used a variable to hold the server and share path and used the variable in the connection string. Not sure why that works put hard coding it in didn't? But it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Greenspark I think you are right! I was using an expression to append the date to the end of the file! I bet that was overwriting my connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an expression to append the date to the end of the file! It seems that the expression was overwriting my connection string.